# How can I initialize a variable of template type in a default constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I am making a Node struct and would like to make a default constructor that initializes each member variable.

```
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    T datum;

    Node()
    { 
        next = nullptr; 
        prev = nullptr;
        datum = ??????
    }
};
```

Since datum is of type T, which is a template type, what can I set datum equal to here? Setting it to NULL is giving me a compiler error.

EDIT: To clarify, I want to initialize the variables so I can modify them later in my code.

Comment: What should it be set equal to? Does it matter if `T` is an integer type? A string type? A class that you've never seen before?

Comment: Technically, you *are* modifying `datum` later in your code, as it gets initialized in your (empty) [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), then modified by the assignment statement in the body of your constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
struct Node {
    Node* next = nullptr;
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    T datum{};

    Node() = default;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! If you write the default constructor as

```
Node(){}
```

initialization will be handled automatically.

Comment: This is not correct. With that implementation, there is no guarantee that `next` and `prev` will be initialized to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is:

```
Node() : next(nullptr), prev(nullptr), datum()
{ 
}
```

Please note that it will fail if `T` is not default constructible.

Answer (score 0):

If `T` is some class and it has default constructor declared, then you don't have to do anything at all. The member will be just initialized by default.

If you need to call specific constructor, there's quite a lot of possibilities:

- first, you can just set initializer at member declaration. I.e. `T datum { };` or `T datum { 1 /*, other args*/ };`. That is it;
- second, you can provide initialization in constructor. Like `Node() : datum { /*blah-blah */ } { /* the body */ }`. Just don't forget to initialize `next` and `prev` as well;
- third, you can use `T` just as if it's type. I.e. you can write something like `datum = T(/* args go here */);` or `datum = T { /* yeah, here too */ };` in your constructor. Little note is to be made however: it's not initialization, it's assignment after initialization. The initialization is to be done through first two options;

A complete example:

```
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
    T datum { 0 }; // for all constructors

    Node() : datum { 1 } // for this particular constructor
    { 
        next = nullptr; 
        prev = nullptr;
        datum = { 2 }; // assign new value now
    }
};
```

Not sure if you need the following, but just in case (and for future generations :) ).

If classes that are going to be used as `T` don't have viable constructors, or they have different arguments, or something else prevents you from using one initializer for them all...

You can oblige those classes to have static field like `default_value` and copy constructors. Then you can initialize like that: `T datum = T::default_value;`. The static field can be replaced with variable template.

Or if you really need to, you can define something like a proxy. Now that we have copy ellision you can define function template that gives you the desired value.

It will look like this:

```
template <typename T>
T default_value() { return { /* very default arguments */ }; }
// or if you don't need that very default body:
// T default_value();
template <>
A default_value<A>() { return { /* A constructor arguments */ }; }
template <>
B default_value<B>() { return { /* B constructor arguments */ }; }
```

So in `Node` you can declare member like `T datum = default_value<T>();`. In C++17 it doesn't require class to have copy constructor or something else, you have only to construct it somehow in `default_value` function's return statement, when you already know the specific class. So no modification of the class is to be done. And yes, that function can have arguments, which you can provide in `Node()` constructor;